# How can I deploy a Web API service to Azure using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am able to publish a webapi to azure from VS, but I have to hand over my source code files to an admin and he needs to deploy the website to Azure.

Can I do it using Powershell, so that I can give him the script and he just has to run it?

I have referred few articles online like [this one](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_webjob_sftp#powershell) but not sure why other dlls are reuired for this job.

I'll appreciate if someone could point to right direction.